# Camera Pose Estimation

Tags: cameras

What is the minimum number of point correspondences required for camera pose estimation given the perspective projections of points with known world coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is called perspective-n-point. And has the answer in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective-n-Point).

6 unknowns. 3 for rotation and 3 for translation.

Each perspective measurement provides 2 points of information. (x,y) in pixels.

$\frac{6}{2}$ is 3.